# How to detect the completion of launching an app?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7

In Windows Phone, there is [Application.LoadCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.loadcompleted.aspx) for detecting the finish of starting an application.

Note the finish means that users are able to interact with the app.

Is there similar API on Android? Any other approaches to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

after `onResume()` gets called it means the user can start interacting with your app. Consult [this document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can override onCreate method of main Activity.

Comment: Or rather onResume as the app is not loaded before onCreate has completed. Besides, I cannot imagine he has not encountered onCreate, whereas onResume is not automatically included when setting up a new project.

Comment: The app may not be foreground or interacting with users in onStart(), not to mention onCreate(), which happens before onStart(). FYI: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by 'finished starting'. Activities, including the main activity, can be created and destroyed - and therefore onCreate() called - multiple times, for example (in the default behaviour) when the device orientation changes. onResume will be called even more often, for example every time the activity comes to the foreground. Then there's onStart(). See the Android developer docs to see when in the lifecycle each is invoked. It's true that the *first* time onResume() is called on the main activity will be when the app is fully started, but you won't know it's the first time without storing state somewhere outside any activity, for example on a singleton, or by subclassing the Application class, which is not something especially encouraged, as far as I can tell.